# The annotation "@Gedmo Slug does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded

Tags: symfony, slug, doctrine-extensions

In the localhost all things work fine but after I have deployed th project I get this error

```
[Semantical Error] The annotation "@Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation\slug" in property 
AppBundle\Entity\Product::$slug does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.
```

This is the class Product

```
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
abstract class Prodcut
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
 */
 private $name;

/**
 * @var string
 * @Gedmo\slug(fields={"name"})
 * @ORM\Column(name="slug", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
 */
private $slug;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you defined alias for the annotation:

```
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
```

and then used it as `@Gedmo\slug(fields={"name"})` which interpolates to:

```
@Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation\slug(fields={"name"})
```

Correct name is with capital `S`:

```
@Gedmo\Slug(fields={"name"})
```